# CakePHP, getting the id of a record from a db table

Tags: database, cakephp

I know getting the `id` of a `record` from a `db table` in `CakePHP` is easy. I want to get the "future" `id` of a "future" `record` of a table, that is, I'll insert a `record`, but before inserting, I want to get its id, which will be generated by db after insertion is completed(the `id` is int, Auto Increment). Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to know the ID before you insert? There shouldn't be any need for that. It's likely your coding conventions are not right if you are needing the ID before inserting.

Answer (score 4):

Even the database itself doesn't know what ID it's going to use until the very moment after the record is saved.

You can't (in a multi-user system) ask in advance what the ID is going to be because 20 other records may have been inserted between the time you ask what the ID is going to be, and when you insert your record (with an ID that was used 20 records ago.) This is called a 'Race Condition'.

Here's what will happen:

```
You: DB - what's the next ID please?
DB: (Does a max() on the column) 21!
You: Great! I'll use that!

(meanwhile 20 other records get inserted by other users)

You: Hi DB, I'd like to insert this record using ID 21 like you told me!
DB: Oops - sorry - that ID has already been used :'-(
```

You don't NEED to know the record in advance. If you structure your save data correctly, and use CakePHP's saveAccociated() method, CakePHP will insert the correct ID as the foreign key value for all your related data.

The only way to have a predictable ID is to create it yourself. Remember - it MUST be non-null and unique (the definition of a primary key).

Save yourself many, many future primary key clashes and stick to the cake method :-)

Answer (score 1):

One option is you can get the current max id from mysql and then just increment the value. If you have alot of operations going on this might cause some trouble with your site. But you could use:

```
$this->Model->query("SELECT MAX(id) as max FROM `your_table_name`");
```

This would get you the max id of that table currently then you can do a +1

Another option would be to get the ID after you save, then update your record with that ID. For example cakephp has a method for this.

```
$this->Model->getLastInsertID();
$this->Model->updateAll($fields, $conditions)
```

Reference updateAll: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-array-conditions

Comment: SELECT MAX wont work. What if 20 records are inserted between the time you ask and the time you use the ID?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the first idea, but I didn't know that it might cause some trouble. Why it might cause trouble ? Can you explain me ? And, doesn't CakePHP have any function or something to give me the last id, before insertion ? Doesn't CakePHP support this kind of operation in any easy way ?@Sixthpoint

Comment: Like explained below, other operations happen before you use that ID you just inserted. I didn't know the context in which you would being using this. Not really the best practice to get the ID before you inserted. But if you had NO other option, you should probably lock the table so no other transactions occur: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: No database can guarantee what an autosequence field is going to be before it saves the record. The save is atomic.